# How to override Jenkins' random image tag for a Dockerfile agent in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I have a step in my Jenkinsfile that runs using a `Dockerfile` agent. When jenkins creates the docker image it gives it a random long tag and I'd like to replace that with my own tag. I tried passing the tag using `additionalBuildArgs` but that gives the docker image an additional tag.

```
agent {
        dockerfile {
            additionalBuildArgs '-t my-image:latest'
        }
}
```

Is there a way to stop Jenkins from passing a tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin that controls this action is [pipeline-model-definition-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-model-definition).

you can see at the [plugin's code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/master/pipeline-model-definition/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/DockerPipelineFromDockerfileScript.groovy#L80) that the image name is a hash of the project name and the dockerfile path:

```
def hash = Utils.stringToSHA1("${runWrapper.fullProjectName}\n${script.readFile("${dockerfilePath}")}")
def imgName = "${hash}"
```

then it takes the additional args and adds them to the image name:

```
def additionalBuildArgs = describable.getAdditionalBuildArgs() ? " ${describable.additionalBuildArgs}" : ""
script.sh "docker build -t ${imgName}${additionalBuildArgs} -f \"${dockerfilePath}\" \"${describable.getActualDir()}\""
```

so by using the dockerfile step, it seems that the name would always be a hash.

Comment: Any way I can read this `imgName` in one of the stages to do stuff with the built image?

Comment: @yarafed Unfortunately after spending a lot of time trying to get this to work, I realized that the declarative syntax was useless for what I was trying to do. To this day, there's hardly been any activity in the relevant Jenkins JIRA tickets about this issue.
I had to switch to the imperative syntax and do `docker.build()` myself in a `script` block; that was the only way.

Comment: @AttilaSzeremi thanks a lot for your response! I also decided to switch to the imperative syntax.

Comment: The tag is still generated as [a hash](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/d5d2e5c4007f7ea006152542b2bcbe0f1b2b08aa/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/declarative/DockerPipelineFromDockerfileScript.groovy#L72).